# laravel Search form

Tags: laravel, search

I am learning about search right now and it uses get method for its' form. So, I tried to change the method into post, but when I tried it, it shows page expired. Can anyone tell me why? Here are my codes.

Master.blade.php

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="/main/successlogin">
      <input name="cari" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/main/successlogin', 'MainController@successlogin');
```

MainController.php

```
function successlogin(Request $request){
    if($request->has('cari')){
        $data_barang=\App\barang::where('namaBarang','LIKE','%'.$request->cari.'%')->get();
    }
    else{
        $data_barang = \App\barang::all();
    }
    return view('halamanUtama', ['data_barang' => $data_barang]);
}
```

Comment: You have to add a  [csrf token field](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction) into your form.

Comment: May I recommend `laravelcollective/html` package, it has a `Form::open(...)` method that automatically takes care of the csrf token. There are also many other handy features like input prefilling

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the CSRF token to your form - you can use the `@csrf` tag for that, you can read more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction)

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="post" action="/main/successlogin">
      @csrf
      <input name="cari" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: anytime, please don't forget to accept the answer so it can help others as well 